# Get total time difference between two dates using php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Here i mention two times with its date

> 2008-12-13 10:42:00
>
> 2010-10-20 08:10:00

I want to get total time difference in (h:m:s)  format

Comment: See this Question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: Just check the question @tarion linked, and use the most voted (not the accepted) answer, using Datetime's diff: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: -1. If you google "php difference between two dates" the exact duplicate that Tarion linked is the first result.

Comment: THIS IS NOT a duplicate of the question linked to, in fact I found this answer MUCH more helpful...can we remove the duplicate from this question?

Answer (score 34):

If you are using or able to use PHP 5.3.x or later, you can use its DateTime object functionality:

```
$date_a = new DateTime('2010-10-20 08:10:00');
$date_b = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:42:00');

$interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);

echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

You can play with the format in a variety of ways, and once you have dates in DateTime objects, you can take advantage of a lot of different functionality, for example comparison via normal operators. See the manual for more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable replay

Comment: Actually, the above is PHP 5.3.x or later

Comment: You're right, I think that was a (very old) typo. Updated, and thanks!

Comment: it gives only difference what if i want whether diff is positive or negative

Comment: You can use the "%R" format string to represent whether it is a positive or negative interval; see http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php for a full list of format options.

Answer (score 16):

what im using:

```
$seconds = strtotime("2010-10-20 08:10:00") - strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");

$days    = floor($seconds / 86400);
$hours   = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400)) / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours * 3600))/60);
$seconds = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes*60)));
```

you can format now in your way

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable replay.with the help of above codes ,i got the answer     $seconds = strtotime("2000-03-01 10:02:00") - strtotime("2000-02-28 10:02:00"); $days    = floor($seconds / 86400);
$hours   = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400)) / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours * 3600))/60);
$seconds = floor(($seconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes*60)));$ff=$days*24;echo $time = $ff+$hours."hours".$minutes."minutes".$seconds."seconds";

Comment: "The floor($seconds / 86400);" will fail on "summertime" dates unless time is specifically added to the date. Else it will be 1 hour off and finding the amount of dates will be 1 day too little (due to it being 1 hour short). Use DateTime and date_diff instead

Answer (score 4):

You can use the the [strtotime function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to turn the time to integers and subtract them.

```
$time1 = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$time2 = strtotime("2010-10-20 08:10:00");

$diff = $time2-$time1;
// the difference in int. then you can divide by 60,60,24 and 
// so on to get the h:m:s out of it
```

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable replay